reference for SAT formula for connectedness
SAT formulas for connectedness of a set of nodes in a graph can be constructed, basically by specifying the distance of each node to a source node, see for example the answers here:
Boolean constraints for a connected component of a graph
and
SAT algorithm for determining if a graph is disjoint
My question: is there a reference of the use of this approach in the literature?
